Getting an error while try to do Composer self update
I am trying to update composer using following command,
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer self-update --2   
But i am getting an error,
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer self-update --2      


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  curl error 28 while downloading  Connection timed out after 10035 milliseconds  


self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys] [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--1] [--2] [--set-channel-only] [--] [<version>]   


C:\xampp\htdocs>https://getcomposer.org/versions:

Any solution for this error?
I am using windows platform for running XAMPP.
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer self-update --2

That's a network error. It's on your end.
